# How do I get one column of an array into a new Array whilst applying a fancy indexing filter on it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So basically I have an array, that consists of 14 Columns and 426 rows, every column represents one property of a dog and every row represents one dog, now I want to know the average heart frequency of an ill dog, the 14. column is the column that indicates whether the Dog is ill or not [0 = Healthy 1 = ill], the 8. row is the heart frequency. Now my problem is, that I don't know how I can get the 8. column out of the whole array and use the boolean filter on it

I am pretty new to Python. As I mentioned above I think that I know what I have to do [Use a fancy indexing filter] but I don't know how I can do this. I tried doing it while still being in the original Array but that didn't work out, so I thought I need to get the Infos into another one and use the Boolean filter on that one.

EDIT: Ok, so here is the code that I got right now:

```
import numpy as np

def average_heart_rate_for_pathologic_group(D):

    a=np.array(D[:, 13])    #gets information, wether the dogs are sick or not
    b=np.array(D[:, 7])     #gets the heartfrequency
    R=(a >= 0)              #gets all the values that are from sick dogs
    amhr = np.mean(R)       #calculates the average heartfrequency
    return amhr
```

Comment: You contradict yourself. If every column represents one dog, how can you also say that the "8 column is the heart frequency"?

Comment: Upvote for the word fancy

Comment: get it into a Pandas dataframe and then post the .head() of your df here so that we can understand your data shape

Comment: A question that hasn't even posted a code snippet or sample data, and is contradicting itself, is getting more upvotes than answers.

Comment: Do you want to get the 8. column or the 8.row?

Comment: @CodePope To make it clear, I want the data of all 426 Dogs and by data I mean the 8. property of them so that should be the 8. column.

Comment: But you said in your question that each row is a property, thus you have 426 properties and you said in the question that each column is a dog so you only have 14 dogs

Comment: I just recognized that I fucked up that part, I have 426 dogs and 14 properties the question should now be edited so that it is right.

Answer (score 1):

I think boolean indexing is the way foward.
The shortcuts for this work like:

```py
#Your data:
data = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...],[..]...]
#This indexing chooses the rows in the 8th column that equals 1 and then their
#column number 14 values. Any analysis can be done after this on the new variable
heart_frequency_ill = data[data[:,7] == 1,13]
```

Comment: Nice solution, but you have to use 13 instead of 14

Comment: @CodePope Thanks! always the small things

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll have to actually copy the data from the original array into a new one with the selected data.

Could you please share a sample with let's say 3 or 4 rows of your data?

I will give a try thought.

Let me build `data` with 4 columns here (but you could use 14 as in your problem)

`data = [['c1a','c2a','c3a','c4a'], ['c1b','c2b','c3b','c4b']]`

You could use `numpy.array` to get its *nth* column.
See how one can get the 2nd column:

`import numpy as np
a = np.array(data)
a[:,2]`

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the Array as a .npy file, the code I have looks like this `import numpy as np

def average_heart_rate_for_pathologic_group(D):

    a=np.array(D[0:14, 426])
    b=np.array(D[0:8, 426])
    A=(a >= 0)
    R = a[b >= 0]
    amhr = np.mean(R)
    return amhr`

Comment: you can implement your own filters like functions with 

`def my_filter(in_array):
...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the 8. Column of all the dogs that are healthy, you can do it the following:

```
# we use 7 for the column because the index starts by 0
# we use filter and fancy to get the rows where the conditions are true
# we use n.argwhere to get the indices where the conditions are true
A[np.argwhere([A[:,13] == 0])[:,1],7]
```

If you also want to compute the mean:

```
A[np.argwhere([A[:,13] == 0])[:,1],7].mean()
```